# Definability of transitivity in modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am reading Yde Venema's text on Temporal Logic found here:
https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/y.venema/papers/TempLog.pdf

Temporal Logic differs from regular Modal Logic by having two non-classical connectives, namely 'henceforth' G and 'hitherto' H. In this question, only G matters. The *truth* value of $G\varphi$ at point $t$ is defined as follows:
$\mathcal{M}, t \models G\varphi \text{ if } \mathcal{M}, s \models \varphi \text{ for all }s\text{ with } t < s$

In section 3.2 Validity and Definability, he introduces how a class of frames $\mathsf{C}$ in $\mathsf{K}$ can be characterised by a formula $\varphi$ by saying:

> formula $\varphi$ *defines* a class of frames $\mathsf{C}$ if for every frame $\mathcal{T}$ in $\mathsf{K}$, $\mathcal{T} \models \varphi$ iff $\mathcal{T}$ belongs to $\mathsf{C}$.

As an example, he works out why the formula $PFq \rightarrow Pq\vee q \vee Fq$ models the calss of frames that have a non-branching future for all time ponits $t\in\mathcal{T}$.
Later, there is an off hand remark that, just like in regular modal logic, $Gp \rightarrow GGp$, models transitivity, which I have difficulty proving.

That transitivity implies $\mathcal{T} \models Gp \rightarrow GGp$ is quite trivial, but the other way around, I only mange to rewrite the statement $\mathcal{T} \models Gp \rightarrow GGp$ to

$\left(\forall_{s>t}\; \mathcal{M},s \models p\right) \rightarrow \forall_{s>t}\forall_{j>s}\;\mathcal{M},j \models p$

And I do not see how this implies that $\mathcal{T}$ is transitive.

Comment: Assume that $T$ is **not** transitive and manufacture a counter-model for $Gp \to GGp$.

Comment: Maybe useful [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924681/mathcalm-models-box-phi-rightarrow-box-box-phi-for-all-phi-if-and).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks, I had not looked at it this way, and I seem to quickly find an answer. Let $\mathcal{T}$ not be transitive, then there are points $t,s,j$ such that $t < s$, $s < j$ and $t \nless j$. Let $p$ be evaluated true for all points $k > t$, and evaluated false for all other points. Then $Gp$ is evaluated true at point t, but $GGp$ is evaluated false.